# Possibly difficulties of mass producing silver bullets

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, werewolf

Other than obvious increase in price what are the functional difficulties in using and mass producing silver bullets to kill were wolves?

Comment: silver is much harder than lead and will do significant damage to barrel of the gun if used often.

Comment: @John: Few guns use simple lead bullets these days. It is usually alloyed to make it harder, and often encased in a jacket of copper alloy.

Comment: Are we assuming modern refining and manufacturing techniques? And how much silver content is needed to be deadly to werewolves? (Is 1% good enough? 50%? 99%?)

Comment: What kind of weapons are we looking at? Black-powder arms? Revolvers? Modern sidearms? Machine guns? Each will have its own implications for using silver rather than other materials.

Comment: @JohnDallman which is only slightly harder than lead, for comparison on the rockwell B scale lead is 5, copper is 10 and silver is 60.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be interested in this. The author went to the trouble of making and eventually shooting some silver bullets through ballistic gel and talks about the difficulties of making molds etc. There were interesting results due to the hardness of the silver. It also has a page on making silver tipped bullets, by filling hollow points with silver which is apparently easier.

http://www.patriciabriggs.com/articles/silver/silverbullets.shtml

Answer (score 4):

Storing the rounds. Silver corrodes, so this may cause a lot of rounds to become unusable overtime. this would also cause problems with shipping as they would have to have special handling practices. But that's the only two things I can really think of.

Comment: silver does not corrode any worse than copper or lead.

Answer (score 3):

**Can you silver plate the lead and still have it work?**

You can make the magic how you want it.  Assuming lead is cheaper (and slightly heavier) than silver, maybe you could make lead bullets and then silver plate them.  If a thin layer of silver = silver bullet for werewolf purposes that would save a lot of money.

I am thinking now of old fashioned firearms where the bullet was just a piece of metal and the powder was separate.  If these are modern bullets where the propellant is integral to the bullet you would not want to silver plate one of those.